# Preventing amnesia so that I can remember where my keys were (and all my other stuff)

Tags: nethack

Late game, I had made it to the Wizard's Tower.  Lovely lovely, doing well.

Pretty sure that I had wished for GDSM (though I have since died, so can't check), but something was bothering me.  Once I killed Rodney I'd thought I was fully prepared for his harassment, but poof, he cast amnesia on me, and I forgot what everything was.

My question is, does GDSM provide MR so that amnesia fails?  And if not, how can I prevent magic from affecting me late game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wizard of Yendor can't cast amnesia, it isn't a spell effect. The only sources in vanilla nethack are scrolls of amnesia, which can be avoided by not reading them; or mind flayers/master mind flayers, which are often avoided through genocide. The Wizard of Yendor *is* capable of summoning master mind flayers through the summon nasties monster spell, whether he is present or not.

If genocide is implausible, a greased helmet also defends against the amnesiac int-drain attacks, although the grease can wear off.

Mind Flayers and Master Mind Flayers are both represented by a purple h, the same symbol as a dwarf king. Be careful that you know what you are attacking.

Comment: Hum, I did see some mind flayers...I wonder if one of them got into my brain when I wasn't paying attention....good to know!

Comment: @MarkB Cloaks do nothing against mind flayers.  You need a greased helmet.

Comment: Note that Mind Flayers respect Elbereth. So you can use all the various Elbereth techniques to keep them from attacking and sucking your brain.